# Pandas: aggregation on multi-level groups

Tags: pandas

I have a df that looks something like this:

```
      batch    group  reading  temp  test    block  delay
   0   9551  Control      340  22.9     1    X     35
   1   9551  Control      345  22.9     1    Y    35
```

I need to group by 'group' and 'block', e.g. my means would look like so:

```
df.groupby(['block', 'group']).reading.mean().unstack().transpose()

block       X           Y
group                          
Control  347.339450  350.427273
Trial    347.790909  350.668182
```

What would be the best way to call a 2 argument function like scipy.stats.ttest_ind on data sliced this way so I end up with a table of t tests for

control vs trial in x

control vs trial in y

x vs y in control

x vs y in trial

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to group and aggregate the data before applying the t-test? I think you want to select subsets of the data. Grouping can do that, but masking might get the job done more simply.

Offhand, I'd say you want something like

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(df[(df.group == 'Control') & (df.block == 'X')].reading, 
                      df[(df.group == 'Trial') & (df.block == 'X')].reading)
```

Comment: Masking is an obvious answer but I'm hoping there is something more elegant that can work with the groupby structure so that if the grouping is changed, you don't need to also go and update your selections

Comment: Interesting. None of the ideas I've just tried have panned out, but I'll chime in again if I think of anything.